# Cross Validation on Training and Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have 500 instances of student dataset and 10 attribute. If I am dividing 170 for training, 330 for testing. These ration is correct for crossvalidation?

Comment: Most people would rather do it the other way around, keeping more of the data available for model-building.  But it's not a matter of "correct" or "incorrect."  Maybe you could say what is the purpose of the cross-validation--your own knowledge?  Making a case for someone else?  Explanation?  Prediction?

Answer (score 2):

For 10 fold cross validation you will:

1. Split the data into 10 subsets of 50 each.
2. For 10 interations choose one subset of 50 to be the validation set and train a model on the remaining 450 instances and record performance on the validation set.
3. Take results of the 10 performance metrics you used for each iteration (AUC, RMSE, etc.) and average them.

This averaged performance metric is your estimate of how the final model will perform on out of sample data.

The final model you deploy will be built on all 500 instances.